# How to handle the DBNull with Expression in this case?

Tags: c#, linq, dbnull

I have use the following code snippet to some Comparison

```
Expression.Constant(DBNull.Value, typeof (Int32));
```

While execute these lines I got the following Exception

```
System.ArgumentException occurred
HResult=-2147024809
Message=Argument types do not match
Source=System.Core
StackTrace:
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant(Object value, Type type)
InnerException:
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32.Null` instead of *`DBNull.Value`*

```
Expression.Constant(SqlInt32.Null, typeof (Int32));
```

Comment: I got the same exception from the code snippet provided in your previous update and also we need use different datatypes instead of particular DataType(Int32)